# TypeError on dot product between dataframe and array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, keras

So I'm trying to build a regression model and I get a "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' " error. 
My code looks like this:

```
dataset_path = keras.utils.get_file("nursery.data",
                                    "path",
                                    cache_subdir="local_path")

column_names = ['parents', 'has_nurs', 'form', 'children', 'housing',
                'finance', 'social', 'health', 'result']
raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names=column_names,
                          na_values="?", comment='\t',
                          sep=",", skipinitialspace=True)
```

After this and a bit of changing values from strings to ints, my X dataframe for training looks like this (snippet):

```
          parents  has_nurs  form children  housing  finance  social  health
6966         1         1     3        2        2        1       2       2
12445        0         0     2        3        1        1       0       1
8358         1         0     1        3        0        1       0       2
10538        0         2     3        4        2        1       0       0
3931         2         0     1        1        0        1       0       1
```

Then I'm trying to do a dot product with the weights:

```
def propagate(w, b, X, Y):


    m = X.shape[1]

    A = relu(pd.DataFrame.dot(X, w) + b)  # compute activation
    cost = (- 1 / m) * np.sum(Y - A)  # compute cost

    dw = (1 / m) * np.dot(X, (A - Y).T)
    db = (1 / m) * np.sum(A - Y)

    assert (dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert (db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert (cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost
```

In this function. Problem is I get a "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' " error no matter what I try. I believe it might be because I have Strings in my column names but I don't know how to get rid of those column names.

W here is the correct shapes (total_rows, 8) for X and (8,1) for W. Please help I have literally no more ideas on how to handle this

Comment: My guess is that one of the arguments to the dot is an array (or Series/Dataframe) with object dtype, and one or more of the element is a string.  In Python `'foo'*3` produces 'foofoofoo'.  But this string (or list) replication only works for integers, not floats.

Comment: To get more help you need to identify the problem line, with traceback if needed, and then tell us about the variables in involved.  You haven't even told us how you call `propagate`.  It may also help to know something about this 'no matter what I try'.

Comment: I have managed to find a solution. For those having some sort of similiar problem, check with deftype() to see if all the types of fields are indeed what you want them to be. In my case I had a "1" which appeared to my untrained eye to be integer, but was a actually a String Object and as such I got that error. To be fair the error could have been better described as "Cannot convert String to float" and I would have fixed it faster

Comment: In `pandas` Series that contain strings are given the object dtype., that it is stores strings a base Python strings.  This is different from `numpy` which has its own fixed lenth string dtype.  So yes, just one string the Series will `contaminate` the whole thing.   Looking at the `dtypes` of the dataframe might have shown this.